# Find ONLY HTML Files & Replace Markup Within Them, in PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell

I need to write up a script in PowerShell that will search through a folder, find ONLY HTML files, and replace a certain line of markup that I specify with new markup.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$filePath = 'C:\Users\bettiom\Desktop\schools\alex\Academics'
$processFiles = Get-ChildItem -Exclude *.bak -Filter *.htm -Recurse -Path $filePath

$query = '<html>'
$replace = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">'

foreach ( $file in  $processFiles ) {
     $file | Copy-Item -Destination "$file.bak"

    $arrayData = Get-Content $file
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $arrayData.Count; $i++) {
         if ( $arrayData[$i] -match $query ) {
              $arrayData[$i+1] = $arrayData[$i+1].Replace($query,$replace)
         } else { }
    }
    $arrayData | Out-File $file -Force
}
```

Everything seems to work up until the foreach loop, it then just doesn't execute pass that line.

Any help given will be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using pipelines where you shouldn't, and avoid them where they'd actually be beneficial. Try this instead:

```
$filePath = 'C:\Users\bettiom\Desktop\schools\alex\Academics'

$srch = '<html>'
$repl = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">'

Get-ChildItem -Exclude *.bak -Filter *.htm -Recurse -Path $filePath | % {
  $file = $_.FullName
  Copy-Item $file "$file.bak"
  (Get-Content $file) -replace $srch, $repl | Out-File $file -Force
}
```